# iPhone distribution with IPA with same bundle identifier is an update?

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, ipa

I'm distributing dev versions of an iPhone app to my clients, directly sending him the IPAs (I don't use services like Crashlytics nor Testflight).

The client install these IPAs via iTunes.

When I send a new version (with the same bundle identifier, but incrementing the build number), is it considered as an **update (data are kept)**, or **does it wipe out all data** (which I wouldn't want to)?

Answer (score 1):

It will keep app's data as long as:

- It is the same bundle id.
- User won't delete existing app before installing new version.

> Data: app's documents folder

Note: Keep in mind that if you export an ipa using developer certificate your clients devices UDIDs would have to be included in the provisioning profile of that app. Otherwise, installation will fail.